# Detect bounding box in OCR?

Tags: c++, opencv

I have an image and I obtained a binary image of it. I would expect a rectangular bounding box, but i didn't get it. This is my code:

```
vector<vector<Point>> contours;
Vec4i hierarchy;
findContours(binary, contours, CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0));
/*Mat drawing = Mat::zeros(binary.size(), CV_8UC3);
for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
{
    Scalar color = Scalar(rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0, 255));
    drawContours(drawing, contours, i, color, 1, 8, hierarchy, 0, Point());
}
imshow("contours", drawing);*/

vector<Point> approx, approxRectangle;
Rect bounding_rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
double max_area = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)// xet tung contour
{
    approxPolyDP(Mat(contours[i]), approx, arcLength(Mat(contours[i]), true)*0.02, true);

    if (approx.size() == 4 && isContourConvex(Mat(approx)))
    {
        Rect box = boundingRect(contours[i]);
        if (bounding_rect.area() == 0){
            bounding_rect = box;
            approxRectangle = approx;
        }
        else{
            if (bounding_rect.area() < box.area()){
                bounding_rect = box;
                approxRectangle = approx;
            }
        }
    }
}`
```

This is my image:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You don't get the desired result, because you're looking for *almost* rectangular contours, but this won't work since the contours you're interested in is not rectanglar. You can see (in blue) the approximation of that contour (obtained on my binarized image):

[image]

This shows you that this is not a reliable constraint.

You can easily solve this, in this case, computing the bounding box for each contour, and keep the largest (in green):

[image]

Code:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    // Load image
    Mat3b img = imread("path_to_image");

    // Convert to grayscale
    Mat1b binary;
    cvtColor(img, binary, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

    // Binarize (remove anti-aliasing artifacts)
    binary = binary > 200;

    // Find contours
    vector<vector<Point>> contours;
    findContours(binary.clone(), contours, RETR_EXTERNAL, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0));

    // Compute the bounding boxes
    vector<Rect> boxes;
    for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); ++i)
    {
        boxes.push_back(boundingRect(contours[i]));
    }

    // Find index of largest contours
    int idx_largest_box = distance(boxes.begin(), max_element(boxes.begin(), boxes.end(), [](const Rect& lhs, const Rect& rhs) {
        return lhs.area() < rhs.area();
    }));

    // Draw largest box
    rectangle(img, boxes[idx_largest_box], Scalar(0,255,0));

    imshow("Result", img);
    waitKey();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried this way. But some case, image is skew. I wanna detect 4 corner point and use that to rotate. Have u any suggestion?

Comment: Find largest blob, and use minAreaRect

Comment: Or simply change this code to use RotatedRect instead of Rect, change boundingRect with minAreaRect. The rest should be the same (apart from drawing results)